# What is the fastest method to find all substrings that are contained in a string?

Tags: algorithm, search

I have a large collection of substrings. For example one million of strings like:

```
["abc", "bane", "cadb" ... "one", "mno" ... "zz", "zzz"]
```

I want to find which of these substrings are included into each of input
strings. For example strings like:

```
"abcdefg hijklmnop" (contains "abc", "mno")
"something one, another two, and zzz" (contains "one", "zz", "zzz")
"однажды в студеную зимнюю пору" (contains nothing)
```

It is a search of millions of input strings against millions of substrings. It is important to find all matching substrings, even overlapping ones. What would be the most efficient approach for such a search?

I guess I could build a trigram database, find matching trigrams in input and substrings, and then use slow matching algorithm against resulting smaller dataset. But may be there is a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the origin of [**Aho-Corasick Algorithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm), a **string-searching algorithm** invented by Alfred V. Aho and Margaret J. Corasick, that **matches simultaneously** the occurrences of **all patterns** within the **input text**.

Its running time is `O(n + m + M)` where `n` is the sum of lengths of the patterns, `m`  is the length of input text and `M` is the amount of matches.

If you find **suitable** to use a database as input data is huge take into consideration this **linear time algorithm**.